# Append multidimensional array in select box ajax-json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

My json response :

```
[{"id":"1","color":"red","id_t":"1"},{"id":"3","color":"black","id_t":"1"}]
```

i want to display json response in mySelect with

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#box").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url     : 'getData.php',
            type    : 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : $('#box').serialize(),
            success: function( data ) {
                for(var id in data) {        
                    $('#mySelect').append($('<option>', {
                        value: data[id],
                        text: data[color]
                    }));
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in `success` function:-

```
success: function( data ) {
  $('#mySelect').empty();
  $.each(data,function(i,d){
       $('#mySelect').append($('<option/>', {
           value: d.id,
           text: d.color
    }));
  });
}
```